# Creating list of calendar events that auto updates

Tags: php, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm attempting to make an extremely basic list of calendar events that will automatically update once an event is over. If I were making this with HTML, I would create an ordered list, and each list item would be an event.

Not sure if PHP could make this happen, or how that would work.

Would it be easier to tie this into Google Calendar?

Comment: are you wanting a tutorial to make a calendar or...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could store events in a database and read them out using PHP or any number of other languages.  The basic idea is to get the next n events that have a date/time greater than the current date/time.

But if you're not already familiar with databases and how to interface with them from a web page, Google Calendar could save you a lot of time. You get a lot for free, including multiple calendars, event notifications, multi-day events, sharing between users, and lots more.  Plus Google generates HTML code that can be dropped straight into your web page for a simple embedded calendar.  For more advanced usages, you can use the Google Calendar API (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/).